# HTML/PHP Form not working

Tags: php, forms, html, isset

I have a HTML Form that uses partial PHP to grab the value, the form is basically like an edit account details form.

**The Problem**

I cannot work out why the form is not working and when using `notepad++` to edit my code if I click on the  it shows the start to be a DIV which just confuses the matter even more... When submitting the form it takes you back to the form page with no message so I am lost for a reason..

**Form Page**

```
<form method="POST" action="dev.php">
<!-- Row -->
<div class="row-fluid">

    <!-- Column -->
    <div class="span6">

    <!-- Group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="fname">First name</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $user_fname; ?>" class="span10" />
                <span style="margin: 0;" class="btn-action single glyphicons circle_question_mark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="First name is mandatory"><i></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- // Group END -->

    <!-- Group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="lname">Last name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="<?php echo $user_sname; ?>" class="span10" />
                <span style="margin: 0;" class="btn-action single glyphicons circle_question_mark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Last name is mandatory"><i></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- // Group END -->

    </div>
    <!-- // Column END -->

    <!-- Column -->
    <div class="span6">

        <!-- Group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" class="span10" />
                <span style="margin: 0;" class="btn-action single glyphicons circle_question_mark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="First name is mandatory"><i></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- // Group END -->

        <!-- Group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="phonenumber" >Phone Number:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" value="<?php echo $user_number; ?>" class="span10" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- // Group END -->

    </div>
    <!-- // Column END -->

</div>
<!-- // Row END -->

<div class="separator line bottom"></div>

    <!-- Group -->
    <div class="control-group row-fluid">
        <label class="control-label" for="bio">About me</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea id="bio" name="bio" class="span12" rows="5"><?php echo $user_bio;?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form actions -->
    <div class="form-actions" style="margin: 0;">
        <button type="submit" id="accountdetails" name="accountdetails" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary glyphicons circle_ok"><i></i>Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
    <!-- // Form actions END -->
```

**dev.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['accountdetails'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['fname']) || isset($_POST['lname']) || isset($_POST['email']) || isset($_POST['phonenumber']) || isset($_POST['bio'])) {
        die ("HERE");
    };
};
```

I probably need to drink more Coffee but I cannot for the life of me work out why it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I put the name's in and this did not help, now the URL of the page shows this:

`update.php?fname=Aaron&lname=Hatton&email=me%40aaronhatton.co.uk&phonenumber=0123456789&bio=+18+%7C+London+%7C+Taken&accountdetails=`

any ideas?

Comment: (For one thing): You haven't named your input fields, besides your submit button. Instead of `id="email"` unless if that's what you want, add `name="email"` and do the same for the other(s)

Comment: You're producing your URL from a `GET` method where your method is `POST`. And your input fields still need to be named.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no offence, that does not help... please go into more detail?

Comment: I can't help any further than to tell you to try and change all `POST` occurences to `GET`. Best I can tell you, I have to get on with my work day.

Comment: Fred is right. Change this: method="POST" in form to method="GET" or where you want to retrieve your data use: $_GET['fname'] instead of $_POST['fname']

Comment: @StudioArena I have done that however I would prefer POST over GET and nothing happens, it just goes back to the form page...

Comment: dude..i tested your code on my local and its display your die message `HERE`.

Comment: Try add a value to a button if you check the value with if isset. Add this to button code: value="Submit" and of course if you prefer a $_POST then change form method to: method="post"

Comment: It should work. Try to call a different file from form instead of: action="dev.php" use action="otherfile.php". In the otherfile.php add your PHP code or just try with one field like: echo "FNAME:".$_POST['fname'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the form works perfect and there was some AJAX being used by another coder, removed and surprise surprise it works perfectly!

Damn co-workers!

*Thanks to all that helped!*

Answer (score 0):

One: do what Fred said (name attributes on your input tags).

Two: You're missing the `</form>` tag at the end.

Comment: I have since updated my code to add the </form> at the end and the name (about 2 minutes ago)

Comment: You also have an extra </div>, in case you haven't updated that also

Answer (score 0):

Your form page seems correct, however, since the form updates the user data, look what the dev.php code is doing:

isset() function returns true if the value is set and you manual set the fields so it will evaluate to true.

and in your if statement you are ORing all the conditions so as soon as it finds 1 true condition, it will go into the if statement body and execute die which will do nothing.

so if you want to test, instead of using die, try echo "here" to see if a message is printed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I have tried and no joy, with POST the URL still has the values as though the form method is GET?

Comment: When you use GET, you will be able to see the field values passed in the URL, using POST you won't see anything. Now another suggestion is try submitting your form using ajax. that's what I usually do 95% of the time, this way you won't get a page refresh.

Comment: I have never used AJAX and therefore my understanding is slim if not none, I don't want that to be an option...

Comment: Then inside dev.php do something like this:

`if (isset($_POST['accountdetails'])) {
     $fname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? isset($_POST['fname']) : "";
     // do same for all other fields
     echo $fname;
     // echo for all other fields to see if your getting values from the form. Then you can call update function to update your database
}
`